# How do I use function argument to find exact clicked marker in google maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, xml-parsing, closures

My marker will always displays the last info on click of it. Basically I want to display the corresponding info for each of the clicked markers. here is what I have so far:

```
$(function() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                zoom : 2,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.65654, -79.90138),
                mapTypeControl: false, //will remove the top right corner Map type(Satellite/Map)
                //scaleControl: false,
                navigationControl: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });
            $.get('example.xml', function(xml) {
            $('marker',xml).each(function(i) {
                var $this = $(this),
                    the_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        title: $this.find('label').text(),
                        map: map,
                        clickable: true,
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                            parseFloat($this.find('lat').text()),
                            parseFloat($this.find('lon').text())
                    )});
                        new google.maps.event.addListener(the_marker, 'click', function() {
                        getInfo();
                });
            }); 
        });
    function getInfo() {
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'example.xml',
                dataType:'xml',
                success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).each(function() {
                    $(this).find("marker").each(function() {
                        $(this).find("info"); 
                        $("#newDiv").html($(this).find("info"));
                    })
                })
                }

            })
        $("#newDiv").html($(this).find("info").text());
    }
    });
```

It is like I am getting always the last infowindow on click of my markers, but rather i want the each marker to have its own infowindow open. Now I dont have infowindow's in my example and i have divs in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use array to do it.
like,

```
markers[i] = new Marker({ some options });
new google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
    getInfo(i);
});
```

---

added:

still cannot get why'd you like to get only first marker in xml on click of any markers.
any demo or example? 
if you wanna fetch the info of clicked marker, do it like this.

```
markers[i] = new Marker({ some options });
info[i] = $(this).find('info');
new google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() { 
    $("#newDiv").html(info[i]);
});
```

Comment: Actually I am already looping through the marker tags of xml. I just need somewhere to use the parameter to get it right. But confused....

Comment: Why don't you save all information when you attach click events? any reason to get example.xml everytime click the marker?

Comment: No actually I need to get the first marker tag from xml on click of every marker and fetch the info associated with it. I am open to suggestions, is there a better to do it. Thanks